# How to get the all the urls form this page?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a scrapy project to get all the urls form this page and the following pages, but when i run the spider, i just get one url from each page!. I wrote a for loop to get them all, but nothing changed?
I need to get each ad data into a row in a csv file, how to do that ?

The spider code:

```
import datetime
import urlparse
import socket
import re

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

from cars2buy.items import Cars2BuyItem

class Cars2buyCarleasingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "cars2buy-carleasing"
    start_urls = ['http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("Abarth"), restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="content"]/div[7]/div[2]/div/a')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("695C"), restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="content"]/div/div/p/a'),  callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="next"]'),  callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for l in response.xpath('//*[@class="viewthiscar"]/@href'):
            item=Cars2BuyItem()
            item['Company']= l.extract()
            item['url']= response.url
            return item
```

the output is:

```
> 2017-04-27 20:22:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/>
> {'Company':
> u'/clicks_cache_car_lease.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fleetprices.co.uk%2Fbusiness-lease-cars%2Fabarth%2F695-cabriolet%2F14-t-jet-165-xsr-2dr-204097572&broker=178&veh_id=901651523&type=business&make=Abarth&model=695C&der=1.4
> T-Jet 165 XSR 2dr',  'url':
> 'http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/'}
> 2017-04-27 20:22:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/?leaf=2>
> (referer: http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/)
> 2017-04-27 20:22:40 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/?leaf=2>
> {'Company':
> u'/clicks_cache_car_lease.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jgleasing.co.uk%2Fbusiness-lease-cars%2Fabarth%2F695-cabriolet%2F14-t-jet-165-xsr-2dr-207378762&broker=248&veh_id=902250527&type=business&make=Abarth&model=695C&der=1.4
> T-Jet 165 XSR 2dr',  'url':
> 'http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/?leaf=2'}
> 2017-04-27 20:22:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
> (finished)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, once your for loop processed the first item it hits the `return`, leaves the `parse_item` method and so no other items are processed.

Suggest you replace the `return` with `yield`:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for l in response.xpath('//*[@class="viewthiscar"]/@href'):
        item=Cars2BuyItem()
        item['Company']= l.extract()
        item['url']= response.url
        yield item
```